# Knockout API with multiple endpoints

Tags: api, knockout.js

I have a question regarding working with Knockout and an API over which I have no control. Forgive my vagueness, but to avoid IP issues, I can't give too much more information. Basically, I have a page in my application that requests data from multiple endpoints (10+) which send back a ton of data, much of which is unnecessary. I've developed a way to make observable those fields I care about, so that's not an issue.

My issue is with assembling the UI...I tried merging all the responses into my view model and then creating the UI in the typical knockout way. This makes extracting the necessary data into new objects and posting back to the respective endpoints quite difficult, though, unless I manually code it all.

I then thought of possibly namespacing the responses to keep them separated and iterate over them when it comes time to post back, since they'll be encapsulated for their own endpoints, but I'm hoping someone out there has more experience with a non-REST API and, specifically, working with multiple endpoints in a single view model. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but this is too vague/broad to answer for outsiders. I sympathize with your situation, but based on your text I'd hazard a guess you'll not be able to fit your problem into an on-topic Stack Overflow question. I suggest getting a colleague, peer, or anyone with proper context into your discussion to look for a design to fit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is stopping you from splitting out your separate endpoints into different services or objects. You could use something like RequireJS to setup dependencies for your viewmodel.

Comment: I'm using browserify and my code is highly modularized, but I feel like KO is limited. I managed to come up with a method where I have callbacks associated with each API call that create properties on the view model which themselves are observable and then keep track of those in an array, but there are certainly some weaknesses to the approach. For how complex our UI is, it's probably the only solution. I like KO for simple UI's but I tried telling my team that it wasn't the right solution...unfortunately, I'm too new to have a valid opinion since everything else was dead in the water :|